# va_list misbehavior on Linux

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have some code that converts variadic parameters into a `va_list`, then passes the list on to a function that then calls `vsnprintf`. This works fine on Windows and OS X, but it is failing with odd results on Linux.

In the following code sample:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *myPrintfInner(const char *message, va_list params)
{
    va_list *original = &params;
    size_t length = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, message, *original);
    char *final = (char *) malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int result = vsnprintf(final, length + 1, message, params);

    printf("vsnprintf result: %d\r\n", result);
    printf("%s\r\n", final);

    return final;
}

char *myPrintf(const char *message, ...)
{
    va_list va_args;
    va_start(va_args, message);

    size_t length = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, message, va_args);
    char *final = (char *) malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int result = vsnprintf(final, length + 1, message, va_args);

    printf("vsnprintf result: %d\r\n", result);
    printf("%s\r\n", final);

    va_end(va_args);

    return final;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *test = myPrintf("This is a %s.", "test");
    char *actual = "This is a test.";
    int result = strcmp(test, actual);

    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("%d: Test failure!\r\n", result);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Test succeeded.\r\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of second `vsnprintf` call is 17, and the result of `strcmp` is 31; but I don't get why `vsnprintf` would return 17 seeing as `This is a test.` is 15 characters, add the `NULL` and you get 16.

Related threads that I've seen but do not address the topic:

- [Pass va_list or pointer to va_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369588/pass-va-list-or-pointer-to-va-list)
- [Passing one va_list as a parameter to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548947/passing-one-va-list-as-a-parameter-to-another)

---

With @Mat's answer (I am reusing the `va_list` object, which is not allowed), this comes squarely around to the first related thread I linked to. So I attempted this code instead:

```
char *myPrintfInner(const char *message, va_list params)
{
    va_list *original = &params;
    size_t length = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, message, params);
    char *final = (char *) malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int result = vsnprintf(final, length + 1, message, *original);

    printf("vsnprintf result: %d\r\n", result);
    printf("%s\r\n", final);

    return final;
}
```

Which, [per the C99 spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) (footnote in Section 7.15), should work:

> It is permitted to create a pointer to a va_list and pass that pointer
>   to another function, in which case the original function may make
>   further use of the original list after the other function returns.

But my compiler (gcc 4.4.5 in C99 mode) gives me this error regarding the first line of `myPrintfInner`:

```
test.c: In function ‘myPrintfInner’: 
test.c:8: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

And the resulting binary produces the exact same effect as the first time around.

---

Found this: [Is GCC mishandling a pointer to a va_list passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047362/is-gcc-mishandling-a-pointer-to-a-va-list-passed-to-a-function)

The suggested workaround (which wasn't guaranteed to work, but did in practice) is to use `arg_copy` first:

```
char *myPrintfInner(const char *message, va_list params)
{
    va_list args_copy;
    va_copy(args_copy, params);

    size_t length = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, message, params);
    char *final = (char *) malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int result = vsnprintf(final, length + 1, message, args_copy);

    printf("vsnprintf result: %d\r\n", result);
    printf("%s\r\n", final);

    return final;
}
```

Comment: Your `myPrintf` function is missing a `return` statement.  I would've expected your compiler to warn you about that.

Comment: bah, humbug! Copy and paste failure.

Comment: Your new code is doing exactly the same thing as the old: `original` points to `params`, so passing `*original` is exactly the same as passing `params`.  Your real problem seems to be that you don't understand how `va_list`s work: they're essentially pointers to the argument stack, and the pointer gets incremented as it's used.  So when you use the same `va_list` twice, the second time you're incrementing the pointer past the end of the argument list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Mat notes, the problem is that you're reusing the `va_list`.  If you don't want to restructure your code as he suggests, you can use the C99 [`va_copy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_copy) macro, like this:

```
char *myPrintfInner(const char *message, va_list params)
{
    va_list copy;

    va_copy(copy, params);
    size_t length = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, message, copy);
    va_end(copy);

    char *final = (char *) malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int result = vsnprintf(final, length + 1, message, params);

    printf("vsnprintf result: %d\r\n", result);
    printf("%s\r\n", final);

    return final;
}
```

On compilers that don't support C99, you may be able [use `__va_copy()` instead or define your own `va_copy()` implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259280/c-varargs-va-copy-issues) (which will be non-portable, but you can always use compiler / platform sniffing in a header file if you really need to).  But really, it's been 13 years — any decent compiler should support C99 these days, at least if you give it the right options (`-std=c99` for GCC).

Comment: I'm using GCC w/ C99, but if you'll see my revised question, I have already tried this and the results are not good. Seems to be broken on x86_64.

Comment: That's odd.  I just tried the exact code I gave above on x86_64 Linux and it works for me.

Comment: Here's my exact experience: http://pastebin.ca/2133787 - I don't think I did any different than you. What version of gcc are you using? I updated my post with that info.

Comment: You have some crud in your `myPrintf` function, presumably left over from earlier attempts.  In fact, you're not calling `myPrintfInner`at all, which is probably why fixing it doesn't help.  (Tip: When experimenting with code, _always_ keep a pre-experimentation copy around. Version control systems are good for this, but even a plain old renamed backup copy will work. And learn to use `diff`.)

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. I guess I should treat scraps of code with a bit more respect.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that (apart from the missing return statement) you're re-using the `va_list` parameter without resetting it. That's not good.

Try something like:

```
size_t myPrintfInnerLen(const char *message, va_list params)
{
    return vsnprintf(NULL, 0, message, params);
}

char *myPrintfInner(size_t length, const char *message, va_list params)
{
    char *final = (char *) malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int result = vsnprintf(final, length + 1, message, params);

    printf("vsnprintf result: %d\r\n", result);
    printf("%s\r\n", final);

    return final;
}

char *myPrintf(const char *message, ...)
{
    va_list va_args;
    va_start(va_args, message);
    size_t length = myPrintfInnerLen(message, va_args);
    va_end(va_args);
    va_start(va_args, message);
    char *ret = myPrintfInner(length, message, va_args);
    va_end(va_args);
    return ret;
}
```

(And turn on your compiler's warnings.)

I don't think the footnote you point to means what you think it does. I read it as: if you pass a `va_list` directly (as a value, not a pointer), the only thing you can do in the caller is `va_end` it. But if you pass it as a pointer, you could, say, call `va_arg` in the caller if the callee didn't "consume" all the `va_list`.

You could try with `va_copy` though. Something like:

```
char *myPrintfInner(const char *message, va_list params)
{
    va_list temp;
    va_copy(temp, params);
    size_t length = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, message, temp);
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please see my revised post?

Comment: Edited my answer, with another option.

Comment: Works For Me(tm) on x86_64 with GCC, though I'm "consuming" the copy first. But I'd really suggest sticking with the resetting of the va_list in the caller.